# OracleConnection throwing exception

Tags: c#, oracle, exception, connection

I'm learning how to work with Oracle and am using C#/Visual Studio. Just as a reference, I'm following [this simple tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technology/obe/hol08/dotnet/getstarted-c/getstarted_c_otn.htm), and have all the prerequisites done (database installed and ODAC with dev tools installed). The following code that's supposed to create an object for connection to a database throws an exception saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." and points to 'conn' when I try to run the program:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection ();
```

The same thing happens regardless of whether I pass the connection string as a parameter or not. I have the needed Oracle.DataAccess reference set, so I don't know if I could be missing something else?

The database is installed and works, but that shouldn't have to do anything with this problem.

Comment: Do you have a tnsnames.ora file setup with your connection properties?

Comment: Yes, the file contains connection data. Anything specific I should look out for? I'm using the express edition database, in the file there are entries for XE, EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA and ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA.

Comment: Definitely a bug in ODP.NET... This instruction shouldn't fail, or if it does, it should throw a more explicit exception. No one ever throws a NullReferenceException on purpose ;)

Comment: I've written a simpler tutorial which may help:
http://splinter.com.au/blog/?p=156

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, it looks like the problem occurs because of OS I'm developing on (64x win7)... a colleague on the same team using xp had no problem running the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I remember having difficulties getting the Oracle Data Provider up and running with C# at first too.  My tnsnames.ora file exsted in C:\oracleInstallDir\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN directory.

My tnsnames.ora looked like this:

```
XE=
(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521)))
```

Make sure that you have the Oracle.DataAccess reference added to your C# project.

Then also make sure that you are

```
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;

public class OracleMgr{
  public OracleMgr(){
    string connectionStr = "Data Source=XE;User Id=user1;Password=abc";
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connectionStr);
    do stuff...
  }
}
```